# Angular JS - Select option select option by value id

Tags: angularjs, select

I has made a ng-repeat of all users but what i want is that he selected current user

```
    <select id="taskUser" class="form-control"
            multiple="multiple"
            ng-model="taskUser"
            ng-options="user.ID as user.Name for user in header.users"
            >
    </select>
```

This is my repeater and i show how te list is look like:

```
<select id="taskUser" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" multiple="multiple" ng-model="taskUser" ng-init=" users = header.users[2].id" ng-options="user.ID as user.Name for user in header.users">
    <option label="User 1" value="string:1">User 1</option>
    <option label="User 2" value="string:2">User 2</option>
    <option label="User 3" value="string:3">User 3</option>
</select>
```

To get the current user id i used {{header.user.ID}} than i get the result just: 3

That means that this need to be selected

```
<option label="User 3" value="string:3">User 3</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$scope.taskUser` should be list and defined as `[3]` because you use `multiple`

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o8Lqq9gk/)</kbd>

---

Full code:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) {

$scope.header = {
  users:[
  {ID: 1, Name: "AAA"},
  {ID: 2, Name: "BBB"},
  {ID: 3, Name: "CCC"}
  ]
};
$scope.taskUser = [3];   
}
```

*HTML*

```
    <select id="taskUser" class="form-control"
            multiple="multiple"
            ng-model="taskUser"
            ng-options="user.ID as user.Name for user in header.users"
            >
    </select>

    <pre>taskUser: {{taskUser|json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the selected value in an array `$scope.taskUser = [3];`

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.header = {};
    $scope.header.users = [
        { ID: 1, Name: 'John' },
        { ID: 2, Name: 'Rocky' },
        { ID: 3, Name: 'John'},
        { ID: 4, Name: 'Ben' }
    ];
    
    $scope.taskUser = [3];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select id="taskUser" class="form-control"
            multiple="multiple"
            ng-model="taskUser"
            ng-options="user.ID as user.Name for user in header.users"
            ></select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```